# What's the difference between *d++ and (*d)++ in C?

Tags: c, pointers

as in the title, what's the difference because these two seem to get me the same results?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No they are not the same. Assume that `d` is a pointer to `int`:

```
int n = 0;
int* d = &n;

*d++; // d++ then *d, but d++ is applied after the statement.
(*d)++; // == n++, just add one to the place where d points to.
```

I think there is an example in K&R where we need to copy a c-string to another:

```
char* first = "hello world!";
char* second = malloc(strlen(first)+1);
....

while(*second++ = *first++)
{
 // nothing goes here :)
}
```

The code is simple, put the character pointed by `first` into the character pointed by `second`, then increment both pointers *after* the expression. Of course when the last character is copied which is '\0', the expression results to `false` and it stops!

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what it does.

Comment: The answer is correct, but the example from K&R is bad style, IMHO. As the original question shows, the semantics of the code is not trivial. It may also be slower than equivalent code in a more conventional style, because the compiler has a harder time optimising it. The lecturer in my compiler course profiled a copying procedure written using `*foo++` and it was *way* slower than `foo[i++]` using GCC.

Comment: @Jørgen: How could the creators of C write C code in a bad style? By definition, this is how it's done in C.

Comment: @Jørgen: So your lecturer took one version of one compiler, profiled the resulting code on one piece of hardware, and the definitive result of this is that the `strcpy` implementation sample from K&R is bad because it's slower than some other way to implement array copying?

Comment: The answer is correct but the K&R example is invalidly implemented. i think you want to make two pointers and increment them then, instead of trying to increment the arrays directly. Otherwise good answer i think.

Comment: Also notice that `sizeof(first)` already accounts for the terminating null. No need to add 1. I think you had `strlen` in mind when writing this :)

Comment: @Jørgen One time here on SO, I got a comment that **while(*second++ = *first++);** is a bad style because it doesn't emphasize that there is a loop, but I never heard that this K&R classical compact example is bad-style. I agree with sbi, if the creator of C writes bad code then no body does write good code in C.

Comment: @litb Thanks, I got confused because I wanted to use pointers first, then I decided to use arrays :)

Comment: @litb Thanks too much for your comment about the array, I am useless without a compiler :P

Answer (score 9):

The increment `++` has higher operator precedence than the dereference `*`, so `*d++` increments the pointer `d` to point to the next location within the array, but the result of `++` is the original pointer `d`, so `*d` returns the original element being pointed to.  Conversely, `(*d)++` just increments the value being pointed to.

Example:

```
// Case 1
int array[2] = {1, 2};
int *d = &array[0];
int x = *d++;
assert(x == 1 && d == &array[1]);  // x gets the first element, d points to the second

// Case 2
int array[2] = {1, 2};
int *d = &array[0];
int x = (*d)++;
assert(x == 1 && d == &array[0] && array[0] == 2);
// array[0] gets incremented, d still points there, but x receives old value
```

Answer (score 1):

In the official C terminology, these expressions do give you the same *results*, as they should. In the proper terminology, the "result" of a non-void expression is what that expression evaluates to. Both of your expressions evaluate to the initial value of `*d`, so not surprisingly, the results are the same.

However, an addition to a "result" every expression in C has zero or more so called "side effects". And side effects of these two expressions are completely different. The first expression increments the value of pointer 'd'. The second expression increments the value of '*d' (the pointed value).

Answer (score 0):

The first increments the pointer, the second increments the value pointed to.

As an experiment, try this:

```
int main() {
    int x = 20;
    int *d = &x;
    printf("d = %p\n", d);
    int z = (*d)++;
    printf("z = %d\n", z);
    printf("d = %p\n", d);
    int y = *d++;
    printf("y = %d\n", y);
    printf("d = %p\n", d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They do return the same result, but the state change in your program is completely different.

This is easiest to understand if we just expand out the operations.

```
x = *d++;
// same as
x = *d;
d += 1; // remember that pointers increment by the size of the thing they point to

x = (*d)++;
// same as
x = *d;
*d += 1; // unless *d is also a pointer, this will likely really just add 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a compiler handy.

```
a = (*d)++;
b = (*d);
```

is a==b?  i don't think it is.